# pm2-runtime inside docker container receives SIGTERM - why?

Tags: node.js, docker, pm2

I'm running a virtual machine with docker, which implements our CI/CD infratructure.

docker-compose has an nginx reverse proxy and another service. Essentially, this docker container's start command is a shell script, which creates local copies of files from a central repository. Then this shell script starts (by means of `yarn start`) a nodejs script that selects a couple of services and creates a pm2 application startup json file.

Finally, `pm2-runtime` is launched with this application definition file. This is done by

```
const child = exec(`pm2-runtime build/pm2startup.json`)

child.stdout.on("data", data => { process.stdout.write(data); })

child.stderr.on("data", data => { process.stderr.write(data); })

child.on("close", (code,signal) => {
  process.stdout.write((`pm2-runtime process closed with code ${code}, signal ${signal}\n`));
})

child.on("error", error => {
  process.stderr.write((`pm2-runtime process error ${error}\n`));
})

child.on("exit", (code, signal) => {
  process.stdout.write((`pm2-runtime process exited with code ${code}, signal ${signal}\n`));
})
```

There are about 10 apps managed by pm2, `docker stats` say, the container has memory consumption greater than 850MB. However, I have nowhere put any explicit memory limits. I cannot find any implicit either.

Every now and then the container of services is restarted. According to the dockerd logs its task has exited. That's true: the pm2-runtime process (see above) is reported to be closed because of SIGTERM.

And that's the only message I get related to this. No other pm2 message, no service message, no docker event.

Now I'm seeking advice how to find the cause of this SIGTERM because I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: That's probably the OS killing the process inside the container. Does your Container has enough memory to run? Also keep in mind that 850mb is the current state that Docker informs, the apps, on heavy load can require much more, NodeJS for example has a heap space of 1400MB, if anything goes above that, the OOM Killer usually kills the process.

Comment: Well, the VM has 8GB - `free` shows always enough memory available. If the NodeJS heap space is exhausted, as far as I remember, there would be an error message at least.

Comment: @JeffRSon, hey i have read alot about pm2 running inside docker containers and i found out that it is a bad practice. you should use docker's capabilities to achieve what pm2 gives you (like restart on failure and so on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, it was indeed the snippet inside the question that caused the problem.

`pm2startup.json` references long-running apps. Over time, depending on usage, they produce quite a few logs on stdout and/or stderr. At some point a certain buffer kept by `exec` is filled up and the node process that runs `pm2-runtime` stops. Unfortunately it stops without any kind of hint specifying the reason of the crash. But that's another story.

Solution in my case was to do without `exec` or `execFile`, but take `spawn` instead with the stdio option `{stdio: "inherited"}` (or the verbose version `["inherited", "inherited", "inherited"]`).